# Java NullPointerException in constructor

Tags: java, struct, nullpointerexception

I defined a class with public attributes.

However, when initializing the values in the constructor, I get a `NullPointerException`.

Here is my code:

```
class CacheBlock 
{
    public byte[] data;
    public int frame;
    public boolean ref;
}

public class Cache
{
    private CacheBlock[] blocks;

    public Cache(int blockSize, int cacheBlocks)
    {
        blocks = new CacheBlock[10];    
        blocks[0].data = new byte[blockSize]; //line that causes exception      
    }   
}
```

Comment: After you create the array, what are its elements?

Comment: Yes I see it, seems quite obvious now.

Comment: `CacheBlock` is a `class`, you have to call the constructor when creating each item in the array, `java` doesn't call default constructor when initializing the array like in `C++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue:

```
blocks = new CacheBlock[10];
```

Here the `block` array has been initialized but there is no `CacheBlock` object at index 0 therefore when it accessed in the next line, there is a NPE.

You would need to create `CacheBlock` instances and add it to the `block` array.

For instance:

```
blocks[0] = new CacheBlock();
```

and so on.

Answer (score -1):

```
blocks = new CacheBlock[10];
```

This line, you only allocate the memory, but not initialize it.

You should add

```
blocks[0]=new CacheBlock();
```

above the suspect line.